# Understanding a 400 bad request with API

Tags: php, json, api, laravel

I initially thought there may be an error in my code, but I have done further tests where I am getting strange behaviour, and I was hoping to discover why.  So I have a simple API route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
    Route::post('createProject', ['uses' => 'ProjectAPIController@createProject']);
});
```

This calls a function that simply returns a success messsage

```
public function createProject(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(["Success", 200]);
}
```

The application I built to use this API was getting a bad request response, so I moved into Postman.

Now within Postman, if I do a Post request to this route, and I pass JSON via the body, I see the bad request still.  However, if I change the JSON setting to text, I see the Success reponse.  As such, I have discovered that the API for some reason is no longer liking JSON being sent to it.

Is there any reason this may be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not formatting the JSON correctly:

```
public function createProject(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(["Success", 200]);
}
```

The response should be in this format:

`(data,statusCode)`

So, the above response should be written like this:

```
return response()->json(["Success" => true],200);
```

The data passed to json method's first parameter is associative array and then in the second parameter we pass the status code.

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason the API is not liking the JSON I am passing it though?

Comment: For that, I'll have to see the detailed response returned by the API call. Can you post it?

Comment: Hi, I have checked my logs and I see ModSecurity: JSON support was not enabled

Comment: Right, that explains it. So your request works fine now?

Comment: No, trying to work out what that error means, think it is server related